# bash approach for ease of calling binary with large amount of parameters

Tags: bash

Trying to figure out the best way to automate running
a command that takes a lot of parameters and changing
some of them. Current approach is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 5 more of these
VALUE=42
STUFF=12
CHARLIE=96

# Note that these are not sequential, just a bad example
PARAM[0]='--oneparameter=17'
PARAM[1]='--anotherparam=FOO'
PARAM[2]='--yetanotherparam=BAR'
PARAM[3]='--someparam4=314'
# the above continues for 15 parameters or so
# and then some ones like this one:
PARAM[16]="--someparam=astring${STUFF}.foo"
PARAM[20]="--someparam20=filename${VALUE}.foo"
```

Then I call the binary:

```
./mybinary ${PARAM[@]}
```

and all is well.

Then I change some parameter for the second run:

```
PARAM[1]='--anotherparam=BAR'
VALUE=84
# Here I need to include all lines that depends on VALUE
# for the parameter expansion to work
PARAM[20]="--someparam20=filename${VALUE}.foo"

./mybinary ${PARAM[@]}
```

This continues for 30 runs or so...

The above works but it's ugly and error-prone but I can't
figure out a better way to do it!
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: how about have a loop with RUN NUMBERS , something like  for run in $runs;do  ./mybinary ${run[@]};done  and run points to the array for that particular run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a small number of parameters which change, you could just loop over those.

```
while read exuberance value attrition attitude spin badness; do
    ./mybinary --someparam1=17 \
            --someparam2="$exuberance" \
            --someparam2=BAR \
            --someparam2="$attrition" \
            # :
            --someparam20="astring${spin}.foo" \
            --someparam20="filename${value}.foo"
done <<____HERE
    42 317 xy Thirty7 vitamins 117
    41 3112 bb Virgo pizza 56
    41 3113 az Virgo pizza 37
    69 512 bee Ozone onion 99
____HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use loops:

```
for (( I = 0; I <= 15; ++I )); do
    PARAM[I]="--someparam$((I + 1))=$((I + 1))"
done
VALUE=84
for (( I = 16; I <= 20; ++I )); do
    PARAM[I]="--someparam${I}=filename${VALUE}.foo"
done
```

You can also use a function to automate it:

```
function callbinary {
    local PARAM=()
    for (( I = 0; I <= 15; ++I )); do
        PARAM[I]="--someparam$((I + 1))=$((I + 1))"
    done
    VALUE=$2
    for (( I = 16; I <= 20; ++I )); do
        PARAM[I]="--someparam${I}=filename${VALUE}.foo"
    done
    "$1" "${PARAM[@]}"
}

callbinary ./mybinary 84
```

You can customize that to accept more arguments that can be used to customize the parameters.

Generally you could just make things a little more static:

```
PARAM=(
    [0]='--oneparameter=17'
    [1]='--anotherparam=FOO'
    [2]='--yetanotherparam=BAR'
    [3]='--someparam4=314'

    [16]="--someparam=astring${STUFF}.foo"
    [20]="--someparam20=filename${VALUE}.foo"
)
```

Comment: My example was a bit misleading, see update. No consecutive numbers are used. Just a mixture of strings and integers/floats with no correlation that can be calculated. Sorry!

Comment: @user2812403 Please see update on the other simpler way to declare multiple values to an array. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for your time! Your answer gave me some new ideas. +1 even though I seem to need 15 rep to upvote...

Comment: @user2812403 Besides giving a vote, you could actually click the check mark of the answer you find most helpful. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you will change, you can use paramters to your bash script,

```
/bin/bash your_bashfile change_value1 change_value2
```

then inside your_bashfile, you use `$1`, `$2` to refer to your parameters

```
VALUE=$1
PARAM[1]="--someparam2=$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

One could write a function that accepts a `VALUE` as a parameter and sets `PARAM` entries accordingly.  For example:

```
setParams() {
    VALUE=$1
    PARAM[0]='--someparam1=1'
    PARAM[1]='--someparam2=2'
    ...etc...
    PARAM[20]="--someparam20=filename${VALUE}.foo"
    PARAM[21]="--someparam21=filename${VALUE}.fee"
}
```

For the two runs mentioned in the question, you would say

```
setParams 42
./mybinary ${PARAM[@]}
setParams 84
PARAM[1]='--someparam2=42'
./mybinary ${PARAM[@]}
```

(Any parameters that differ from the defaults that `setParams` sets would need to be set after the `setParams` call.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if pointing to external tools is frowned upon, but this looks like something that a script I stumbled on recently might be able to help out with a bit: [optparse](https://github.com/nk412/optparse). It's a wrapper for getopts that makes defining command line parameters much easier, and as it's written in bash, it doesn't have any dependencies, and you can embed it with the rest of your code.